# The requested URL /drupal/admin/reports was not found on this server

Tags: permissions, 18.10, drupal

I installed Ubuntu 18.10 successfully, Installed LAMP stack, Given read-write Permissions to /var/www/html directory. Installed Drupal 8 while I trying to go any other page other than a home page in Drupal 8 site. I'll get below error

> The requested URL /drupal/admin/reports was not found on this server.

Comment: Check Apache's `mod-rewrite`

Comment: I did it, still same error

Answer (score 1):

Solved this issue by adding the following code in apache2.conf 
what I did is go to /etc/apache2/apache2.conf and paste this code in a file

```
  <Directory /var/www/html/>
     AllowOverride All
  </Directory>
```